# 'DT_REG Undeclared' even when using <dirent.h> header file in function

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, unix

I'm using the <dirent.h> header file in the function I'm referencing DT_REG, however, I'm getting error an saying " 'DT_REG' undeclared (first use in this function) "

The snippet of the code is:

```
  DIR * dirp;
  struct dirent * entry;
  dirp = opendir(path);
  if(entry->d_type == DT_REG) { //.... }
```

In my makefile I'm using "cc -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -pedantic".

Any ideas for the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DT_REG` is not part of ISO C11 extensions. Setting `-std=c11` strictly enables only features defined in C11 standard.

You can use [feature macros](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html) to enable additional extensions. As [readdir manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) mentions, you need `_DEFAULT_SOURCE` macro to enable file type constants.

You can do this in the source code before including `dirent.h`

```
#define _DEFAULT_SOURCE
#include <dirent.h>
```

or via command line as a compiler option

```
cc -std=c11 -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -Wall -Werror -pedantic
```