# I got the error "identifier "DT_REG" is undefined" even when using <dirent.h>. Is that because of IntelliSense?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, intellisense, windows-subsystem-for-linux, dirent.h

I'm using WSL in VScode and getting error "identifier "DT_REG" is undefined" even when I included <dirent.h>. But I can still run this code, so I thought it's because of IntelliSense.

This is my code:

```
DIR *dir = opendir(argv[1]);
struct dirent *entry;
    
while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
{
   if (entry->d_type == DT_REG)
   {

   }
}
```

I tried changing intellisense mode, but I still get that error

Comment: Welcome to SO. When do you get that message? In the editor with some squiggly line? Or when you compile?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['DT\_REG Undeclared' even when using <dirent.h> header file in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69689586/dt-reg-undeclared-even-when-using-dirent-h-header-file-in-function)

Comment: @Gerhardh Nice to meet you. It's a squiggly line error and there 2 quick fix: "Edit "includePath" setting" and "Disable error squiggle"

Comment: Do you define `_DEFAULT_SOURCE` as suggested in the answer to the linked question? Does compiling work? A valid [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should contain everything to reproduce your issue. Please edit your question to include missing code.

Comment: You should also take [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)